# Lower bound of solving a optimization problem

Tags: algorithms, lower-bounds

Suppose given $k$-sorted arrays of numbers that contains total of $n$ elements. we try to choose $k$ elements in $k$ arrays (each arrays exactly one element) such that minimize difference between maximum and minimum number in chosen $k$ numbers. What is lower bound of this problem? I have an algorithm that solve above problem in $\Omega(n\log k)$.

I think this problem related to [$k$-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm). And already I know why the lower bound of $k$-way merge is $\Omega(n\log k)$. But I can't reduce $k$-way merge to above problem.

Comment: What is your computation model? Linear decision trees?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I try to find a lower bound under comparison based models.

Comment: I’m not sure that the vanilla comparison model can solve your problem.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150610/755